# Create context sensitive headings

Tags: sectioning

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`coseoul`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/coseoul)

Is it possible to create headings in LaTeX where you don't specify what level of the heading you want, but rather if you want to go up, down, stay or start over in the hierarchy that the heading is going to be placed within?

That is, instead of writing

```
\section{Level 1}
\subsection{Level 2}
\subsection{Level 2}
\subsubsection{Level 3}
\subsection{Level 2}
\section{Level 1}
```

write something like

```
\sectiontop{Level 1}
\sectiondown{Level 2}
\sectionstay{Level 2}
\sectiondown{Level 3}
\sectionup{Level 2}
\sectiontop{Level 1}
```

If you would use something along these lines, it would be possible to make quick changes. For example, if you suddenly realized that you wanted to place the headings on row 2-5 under a certain heading, you could easily do this by placing a `\sectiondown` before them. If you instead was using the system where you had to specify the level of every heading you would have to make individual changes to all 4 rows.

Comment: There's a related question here: [Is there a program that allows to move sections and automatically adjusts the level of subsections?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9024/2693). Bruno Le Floch's answer seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here you go. It works, but so far only for `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`. It works by defining `\currrentlevel`, which is empty initially, so you need to use one of the new section commands (`\newchapter`, `\newsection`, `\newsubsection` and `\newsubsubsection`). After that you can use `\levleup`, `\levelstay` and `\leveldown`.
You can expand it to `\part`, `\paragraphs` and such, but remember a few things:

- `\levelup` moves exactly one level up, you cant go from `\subsubsection` (e.g. 1.2.3.4) to a `\section` (e.g. 1.3) as that is two levels difference. Either you define a `\twolevelup`, or use `\newsection` (but that would break relativity)
- the order of definitions is important. It is done via `\ifthenelse` constructs, so the `\levleup` definition needs to be top-down (c-s-ss-sss) and `\levledown` needs to be down-up (sss-ss-s-c)
- remember what class you use. `article` does not know `\chapter`s, so trying `\levleup` after a section will probably cause an error
- remember that `\currentsection` is not initialized at the beginning, so initialize it by using e.g. `\newchapter`

---

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\currentlevel}{}

\newcommand{\levelup}[1]%
{   \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{c}}%
    {\chapter{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{c}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{s}}%
    {\chapter{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{c}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{ss}}%
    {\section{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{s}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{sss}}%
    {\subsection{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{ss}}{}%
}

\newcommand{\leveldown}[1]%
{   \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{sss}}%
    {\subsubsection{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{sss}}{}%    
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{ss}}%
    {\subsubsection{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{sss}}{}%    
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{s}}%
    {\subsection{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{ss}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{c}}%
    {\section{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{s}}{}%
}

\newcommand{\levelstay}[1]%
{   \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{c}}%
    {\chapter{#1}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{s}}%
    {\section{#1}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{ss}}%
    {\subsection{#1}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentlevel}{sss}}%
    {\subsubsection{#1}}{}%
}

\newcommand{\newchapter}[1]{\chapter{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{c}}
\newcommand{\newsection}[1]{\section{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{s}}
\newcommand{\newssubection}[1]{\subsection{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{ss}}
\newcommand{\newssubsubection}[1]{\subsubsection{#1}\renewcommand{\currentlevel}{sss}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\newchapter{chapter 1}

\leveldown{ 1.1}
\levelstay{ 1.2}
\levelstay{ 1.3}
\leveldown{ 1.3.1}
\levelstay{ 1.3.2}
\levelup{ 1.4}
\levelstay{ 1.5}
\leveldown{ 1.5.1}
\levelstay{ 1.5.2}
\leveldown{ 1.5.2.1}
\levelstay{ 1.5.2.2}
\levelstay{ 1.5.2.3}
\levelstay{ 1.5.2.4}

\newchapter{chapter 2}

\leveldown{ 2.1}
\levelstay{ 2.2}
\levelstay{ 2.3}
\leveldown{ 2.3.1}
\levelstay{ 2.3.2}
\levelup{ 2.4}
\levelstay{ 2.5}
\leveldown{ 2.5.1}

\end{document}
```

**Edit 1**: I totally   to overhauled it. 
New features:

- checks for existance of `\chapter`, skips it if it does not
- now includes `\part`, `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`
- levels going to high / low are replaced by highest / lowest available
- includes `\levelmultiup`, to go up multiple levels, e.g. from `\subsubsection` to `\chapter` via `\levlemultiup{chapter heading}{3}`

But there are a few things that remain to be done:

- specify maximum / minimum level to be used (if you e.g. don't like `\part`s
- optional warning of some kind when levels are  too low or high so they are changed (and therefore are no longer in the required hierarchy)
- somehow expand the individual outline elements so they set `\currentlevel`, e.g. are better way of initialization than `\setcounter{currentlevel}{7}`

And here's the code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\chex}{}

\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\chapter}}{\renewcommand{\chex}{N}}{\renewcommand{\chex}{Y}}

\newcounter{currentlevel}
% part                  = 7
% chapter               = 6
% section               = 5
% subsection        = 4
% subsubsection =   3
% paragraph         =   2
% subparagraph  =   1

\newcommand{\findnewlevel}[1]% uppity (-1 for level down, 0 for stay, 1 for up, 2-6 for multiup
{   \addtocounter{currentlevel}{#1}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\chex}{N}}%
    {   \ifthenelse{\value{currentlevel} = 6}%
        {   \ifthenelse{#1 > 1}{\addtocounter{currentlevel}{1}}{\addtocounter{currentlevel}{-1}}}{}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{currentlevel} < 1}{\setcounter{currentlevel}{1}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{currentlevel} > 7}{\setcounter{currentlevel}{7}}{}%
}

\newcommand{\levelchange}[2]% title, uppity
{   \findnewlevel{#2}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{currentlevel} = 1}{\subparagraph{#1}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{currentlevel} = 2}{\paragraph{#1}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{currentlevel} = 3}{\subsubsection{#1}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{currentlevel} = 4}{\subsection{#1}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{currentlevel} = 5}{\section{#1}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{currentlevel} = 6}{\chapter{#1}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{currentlevel} = 7}{\part{#1}}{}%
}

\newcommand{\levelup}[1]{\levelchange{#1}{1}}

\newcommand{\leveldown}[1]{\levelchange{#1}{-1}}

\newcommand{\levelstay}[1]{\levelchange{#1}{0}}

\newcommand{\levelmultiup}[2]{\levelchange{#1}{#2}} %title, uppity

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
\newpage

\setcounter{currentlevel}{7}

\levelstay{part}
\leveldown{chap}
\leveldown{sec}
\leveldown{subsec}
\leveldown{subsubsec}
\leveldown{par}
\leveldown{subpar}
\levelstay{subpar}
\levelup{par}
\levelstay{par}
\levelup{subsubsec}
\levelstay{subsubsec}
\levelup{subsec}
\levelstay{subsec}
\levelup{sec}
\levelstay{sec}
\levelup{chap}
\levelstay{chap}
\levelup{part}

\leveldown{chap}
\leveldown{sec}
\leveldown{subsec}
\leveldown{subsubsec}
\leveldown{par}
\leveldown{subpar}
\levelmultiup{part}{6}

\leveldown{chap}
\leveldown{sec}
\leveldown{subsec}
\leveldown{subsubsec}
\leveldown{par}
\levelmultiup{part}{5}

\leveldown{chap}
\leveldown{sec}
\leveldown{subsec}
\leveldown{subsubsec}
\levelmultiup{part}{4}

\leveldown{chap}
\leveldown{sec}
\leveldown{subsec}
\levelmultiup{part}{3}

\leveldown{chap}
\leveldown{sec}
\levelmultiup{part}{2}

\end{document}
```

Which results in the following:

[image: context sensive headings]

Comment: This is really great! Something like this should really be included as a default package. But thanks! I'll try to edit it to suit my exact needs.

Comment: You might want to turn this into a package and put it on CTAN.  Here are some links about that: [How can I contribute to CTAN?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/854/2693); [What is good practice when preparing a package for CTAN:](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25116/2693); Also, if you're unfamiliar with how packages are constructed `texdoc clsguide` will give you a good overview of their basic structure, and useful commands.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Yes, I thought about it too, thanks for the links!

Comment: I wrote a package to incorporate this functionality, I uploaded it on CTAN, and [now it is available there](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/coseoul)

Comment: @TomBombadil Cryptical names are hard to remember. While reading, names come to my mind: `relheadings`, `relsectioning`, or simply `levels` matching your `\level` commands.

Comment: @TomBombadil What do you think about writing an article on our blog, introducing your package?

Comment: You actually created a package? Way to go! :D

Comment: I'd like to contribute an update to the package that was created by this post, but the author's contact info is not recorded in the package documentation. The update is an improvement on the macro proposed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245348/recursively-import-sub-document-at-arbitrary-level). You can find my version, and a demo, on [my github repository](https://github.com/DanielSank/TeXtricks/tree/master/modularity-demo). Please contact me if you're interested.

Comment: What is the easiest way to modify / add to this package to get relative, non-numbered sections? (similar to the * option on normal LaTeX headers)