# Demoting/Promoting sections, chapters, etc

Tags: sectioning

Consider following structure:

```
.
|_s
|_s
 |_ss
 |_ss+
  |_sss
 |_ss
|_s
|_s
```

How can I demote a subsection to subsubsection without changing markups ?

```
.
|_s
|_s
 |_ss
  |_sss+
   |_p
 |_ss
|_s
|_s
```

How can I promote a subsection to section without changing markups ?

```
.
|_s
|_s
 |_ss
|_s+
 |_ss
 |_ss
|_s
|_s
```

A wrapper command would be excellent

```
\begin[+1]{level}
\section{}
\end{level}
```

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26181/create-context-sensitive-headings help at all?

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks, It's strongly related but it is just applicable to new documents.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An easy way to promote/demote sectional commands would be to use a `levelup`/`leveldown` environment:

```
\newenvironment{leveldown}% Demote sectional commands
  {\let\section\subsection%
   \let\subsection\subsubsection%
   \let\subsubsection\paragraph%
   \let\paragraph\subparagraph%
   %\let\subparagraph\relax%
  }{}
\newenvironment{levelup}% Promote sectional commands
  {\let\subparagraph\paragraph%
   \let\paragraph\subsubsection%
   \let\subsubsection\subsection%
   \let\subsection\section%
   %\let\section\relax%
  }{}
```

For promotion (`levelup`), `\section` can either be left as-is, or made into something else. Similarly, for demotion (`leveldown`), `\subparagraph` can either be left as-is, or made into something else.

As an example, consider the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}% Show up to \subparagraph in ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% Number up to \subparagraph
\newenvironment{leveldown}% Demote sectional commands
  {\let\section\subsection%
   \let\subsection\subsubsection%
   \let\subsubsection\paragraph%
   \let\paragraph\subparagraph%
   %\let\subparagraph\relax%
  }{}
\newenvironment{levelup}% Promote sectional commands
  {\let\subparagraph\paragraph%
   \let\paragraph\subsubsection%
   \let\subsubsection\subsection%
   \let\subsection\section%
   %\let\section\relax%
  }{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[3]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[4]
%\begin{leveldown}
  \subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[5]
  \subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[6]
  \subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[7]
%\end{leveldown}
\section{A section}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[3]
%\begin{levelup}
  \subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[4]
  \subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[5]
  \subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[6]
%\end{levelup}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[7]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[3]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[5]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[6]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[7]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[3]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[5]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[6]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

Uncommenting the `levelup` and `leveldown` environments, yields the following ToC:

[image]

The above discussion excludes `\chapter` commands, but that could also be incorporated.

Comment: This used to work with `\chapter` and also with KOMAscript in Texlive 2014 when using `\let\section\addchap` in levelup. This stopped working with the current Texlive. Any idea why? Worth a new question?

Comment: @vanto: I can't replicate the problem as my example works under TL2017, even using (say) `scrbook` with `\let\section\addchap`. Perhaps you can provide a minimal example that illustrates the problem...?

Comment: Thanks for testing. I just figured that it was caused by a side-effect through monkey-patching KOMAscript. Sorry for the noise.