# Renaming section levels?

Tags: sectioning, external-files

I have several reports I've written up in `article` format.

I want to keep them in separate files but combine them into a larger report. I've removed the headers, but don't want to go through each file and relabel each section as a subsection, and so on. Is there a way to handle this programatically? For instance, in my main file I might have

```
\section{Section1}
\input{file1}
```

and in `file1.tex` I have

```
\section{File1Section1}
...
\section{File1Section2}
```

I think some solution might be the redefinition of `\section` before and after each `\input` invocation, or an environment in which I can wrap the `\input` invocation where each `\section` is renamed as `\subsection` and so on. Help?

Comment: Are there `\subsection` headings in the input file?

Comment: Related: [Demoting/Promoting sections, chapters, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61766/5764)

Comment: Not the perfect solution for existing documents but when you next time start a new project and know this might become an issue, consider using relative sectioning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066119/relative-section-specification

Comment: There are indeed `\subsection`-level headings in the file and I had not thought of relative sectioning but will have to keep in mind in the future, though @Werner's solution is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following redefinition of `\input` redefines `\section` to be `\subsection` (as well as for the subsidiary sectioning commands) via `\demotesections`. Of course, this assumes that there are no deeper levels inside the included files than `\subparagraph`. However, it would be possible to set these to `\relax` as a "no-op":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{filecontents,lipsum}
% Create some dummy files
\begin{filecontents*}{file1}
\section{File1Section1}\lipsum[1]
\section{File1Section2}\lipsum[2]
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{file2}
\section{File2Section1}\lipsum[1]
\section{File2Section2}\lipsum[2]
\end{filecontents*}

\let\oldinput\input
\newcommand{\savesections}{%
  \let\oldsection\section% Store \section
  \let\oldsubsection\subsection% Store \subsection
  \let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection% Store \subsubsection
  \let\oldparagraph\paragraph% Store \paragraph
  \let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph% Store \subparagraph
}\AtBeginDocument{\savesections}
\newcommand{\restoresections}{%
  \let\section\oldsection% Restore \section
  \let\subsection\oldsubsection% Restore \subsection
  \let\subsubsection\oldsubsubsection% Restore \subsubsection
  \let\paragraph\oldparagraph% Restore \paragraph
  \let\subparagraph\oldsubparagraph% Restore \subparagraph
}
\newcommand{\demotesections}{%
  \let\section\subsection% Modify \section to be \subsection
  \let\subsection\subsubsection% Modify \subsection to be \subsubsection
  \let\subsubsection\paragraph% Modify \subsubsection to be \paragraph
  \let\paragraph\subparagraph% Modify \paragraph to be \subparagraph
  %\let\subparagraph\relax% Make \subparagraph a no-op
}
\renewcommand{\input}[1]{%
  \demotesections% Demote sections
  \oldinput{#1}% Input file
  \restoresections}% Restore sections
\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
\subsection{Just a subsection}
\section{Section2}
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
\end{document}
```

The sectioning units are first saved using `\savesections`. Redefinition via `\demotesections` is "localized" within the new macro `\input` as a result of  a subsequence `\restoresections`, allowing to use the default sectional units outside without loss of functionality.

Comment: This is mostly, academic but with the other page you linked to, I can wrap each `\input` invocation with a `\levelup` or `\leveldown` environment to have full control over the section depth of the input files I've already created. This is really marvelous.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, before I came back here to see @Werner's elegant solution, I took a stab at it. I will incorporate it into his example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{filecontents,lipsum}
% Create some dummy files
\begin{filecontents*}{file1}
\section{File1Section1}\lipsum[1]
\section{File1Section2}\lipsum[2]
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{file2}
\section{File2Section1}\lipsum[1]
\section{File2Section2}\lipsum[2]
\end{filecontents*}

\newcounter{toplevel}
\setcounter{toplevel}{1}
% 
\newcommand{\open}{
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{toplevel}.\arabic{section}}
}
%
\newcommand{\close}{
  \addtocounter{toplevel}{1}
  \setcounter{section}{\value{toplevel}}
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{toplevel}}
}
% 
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{toplevel}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\open
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
\subsection{Just a subsection}
\close
\section{Section2}
\open
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
\close
\end{document}
```

It sort of works except that the it needs better formatting so the `\thesubsection` is in a smaller font and also the `\tableofcontents` doesn't recognize the demotion of level so the printing is not very pretty. And apart from aesthetics, any `\thesubsection` in the main file will be further demoted (in my kludgey way) when included between the `\open` and `\close` statements. Anyway it's what I could do with my knowledge of `\LaTeX` (basically, `\newcounter`, `\setcounter`, and `\renewcommand`).