# How to nest a pre-written chapter into another chapter without manually changing sectioning commands one by one

Tags: sectioning, nesting

I have a tex file with several written chapters. Then I found I need to nest one of them to another. I know this can be done by manually changing the sectioning command one by one but I found it really time consuming and a bit dumb :p

for example, I now have this document

```
\chapter{big nest}
    \section{a}
    ...
    ...
\chapter{i want to be a section}
    \section{b}
        \subsection{c}
```

I want to nest chapter{i want to be a section} into chapter{big nest} and after compiling, in Table of Contents it should look in a structure like:

```
\chapter{big nest}
    \section{a}

    \section{i want to be a section}
        \subsection{b}
            \subsubsection{c}
```

Question: Is there a clever way to nest an entire written chapter into another chapter?

By the way, I'm sorry for my poor language and hope you understand my question. I also have tried to search for related topic but I don't know the correct words so I got no related search results. Maybe there is, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: See [Demoting/Promoting sections, chapters, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61766/5764) and/or [Renaming section levels?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98413/5764)