# inclusion + nested section

Tags: sectioning

I'm generating some TeX code with XSLT that will be included in a main document. I've have no prior knowledge of the place where it will be included: it could be within a `section` or a `subsection`. How can I create a section just like a set of nested UL in html

```
<ul>
   <li>Hello</li>
   <li><ul>
      <li>World</li>
   </ul></li>
</ul>
```

I tried something like:

```
\begin{section}
Hello
\begin{section}
World
\end{section}
\end{section>
```

but it didn't work: they all have the same depth.

Comment: In LaTeX there's no nesting of sections, and no end marker as well.

Comment: This is the same as HTML really, the analogue of `<ol>` is `\begin{itemize}` which will, like an HTML list, adjust if nested. `\section` is like `<h2>` and doesn't nest, it just marks the heading, leaving the content of the section implicit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your analogy is good. However if I insert a `\begin{itemsize}`, the numbering will be disconnected from the sections of the main document isn't it ?

Comment: So in this instance you want the inner `section` to become a `subsection`?

Comment: Related: [Demoting/Promoting sections, chapters, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61766/5764)

Answer (score 1):

The following implements a `mysection` environment that can be nested, automatically promoting and demoting section types to accommodate the nesting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% Section
\@namedef{section@name@1}{section}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@indent@1\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@indent@1\endcsname{\z@}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@beforeskip@1\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@beforeskip@1\endcsname{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@afterskip@1\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@afterskip@1\endcsname{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}
\@namedef{section@style@1}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
% Subsection
\@namedef{section@name@2}{subsection}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@indent@2\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@indent@2\endcsname{\z@}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@beforeskip@2\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@beforeskip@2\endcsname{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@afterskip@2\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@afterskip@2\endcsname{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
\@namedef{section@style@2}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
% Subsubsection
\@namedef{section@name@3}{subsubsection}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@indent@3\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@indent@3\endcsname{\z@}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@beforeskip@3\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@beforeskip@3\endcsname{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@afterskip@3\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@afterskip@3\endcsname{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
\@namedef{section@style@3}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
% Paragraph
\@namedef{section@name@4}{subsubsection}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@indent@4\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@indent@4\endcsname{\z@}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@beforeskip@4\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@beforeskip@4\endcsname{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@afterskip@4\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@afterskip@4\endcsname{-1em}
\@namedef{section@style@4}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
% Subparagraph
\@namedef{section@name@5}{subsubsection}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@indent@5\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@indent@5\endcsname{\parindent}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@beforeskip@5\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@beforeskip@5\endcsname{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}
\expandafter\newlength\csname section@afterskip@5\endcsname\expandafter\setlength\csname section@afterskip@5\endcsname{-1em}
\@namedef{section@style@5}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}

\newcounter{section@level}
\newcommand{\unstepcounter}[1]{\addtocounter{#1}{-1}}
\newenvironment{mysection}
  {\stepcounter{section@level}%
   \@startsection{\@nameuse{section@name@\thesection@level}}
     {\thesection@level}
     {\@nameuse{section@indent@\thesection@level}}
     {\@nameuse{section@beforeskip@\thesection@level}}
     {\@nameuse{section@afterskip@\thesection@level}}
     {\@nameuse{section@style@\thesection@level}}}
  {\unstepcounter{section@level}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{mysection}{A section}
  Some text.
  \begin{mysection}{A subsection}
    Some text.
    \begin{mysection}{A subsubsection}
      Some text.
    \end{mysection}
    \begin{mysection}{A subsubsection}
      Some text.
      \begin{mysection}{A paragraph}
        Some text.
      \end{mysection}
      \begin{mysection}{A paragraph}
        Some text.
        \begin{mysection}{A subparagraph}
          Some text.
        \end{mysection}
      \end{mysection}
    \end{mysection}
  \end{mysection}
  \begin{mysection}{A subsection}
    Some text.
  \end{mysection}
\end{mysection}
\end{document}
```

The sectional definitions are taken from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

and broken down according to each section's `name`, `level`, `indent`, `beforeskip`, `afterskip` and `style` (see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764)).

With every call to the `mysection` environment, `section@level` is stepped to demote to the next lowest sectioning unit, and "unstepped" at the end of the environment. No testing for end-of-depth is made, but that's possible.