# Alias for chapter with newcommand

Tags: macros, sectioning, chapters

I want some files to compile with two different templates, one that has the hierarchy like chapter > section > subsection and the other as section > subsection > subsubsection.

For that, I tried to define newcommands to act like an alias to the level like:

```
\newcommand{\level1}[1]{\chapter{#1}}

\newcommand{\level2}[1]{\section{#1}}

\newcommand{\level3}[1]{\subsection{#1}}
```

and the in the body I would call \level1{title}. This way I could change from templates only by changing this 3 lines.

I use lines like: `\newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section \ref{#1}}`, but the ones with `\chapter` and so on don't work.

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! have you seen [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718)

Comment: Related: [Demoting/Promoting sections, chapters, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61766/5764)

Comment: For the `\secref` thingy, see the package [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) that does this quite nicely and automatically.

Comment: If you are wondering why your code didn't work, you aren't allowed to put numbers in command names (unless you use \csname).

Answer (score 5):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand\level[1]{
\begingroup\ifcase#1\relax
    \GenericError{}{\string\level\space given an invalid argument}{}{}
    \or\aftergroup\chapter
    \or\aftergroup\section
    \or\aftergroup\subsection
    \or\aftergroup\subsubsection
    \or\aftergroup\paragraph
    \or\aftergroup\subparagraph
    \else\GenericError{}{\string\level\space given an invalid argument}{}{}
    \fi\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\level1{CHCHCH}

\level2{SESESE}

\level2{SESESESE}

\level3{SUBSUBSUB}

\level4{subsubsub}

\end{document}
```

We use the TeX primitive `\ifcase` on the argument. The `\aftergroup` construction is necessary so that the sectioning command is the last thing to be issued by the macro. We use LaTeX's `\GenericError` to generate an error if incorrect input is given.

In `book` class, you might add `\or\part` before `\or\chapter`. In `article` class, on the other hand, you should comment out `\or\chapter`.