# Shorten distance between chapters in book?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, books

Is there a way to shorten the distance between chapters in `\documentclass{book}` so that it is as between sections, and, consequently with no blank page in front of new chapters?

Comment: You can use a package like [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) or change the class. If you expect a real answer, please show a minimal working example.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has migrated to `article` successfully, but without providing details.

Comment: @barbarabeeton See the answer I posted.

Comment: Related: [Demoting/Promoting sections, chapters, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61766/5764)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has migrated to article successfully, but without providing details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very easy solution would be to switch from `book` to [`scrbook`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrbook) and change the style of `\chapter` to `section`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

See the manuals for more information about configuration options.

Other suggestions would be to either use [`titlesec`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titlesec) or replace `book` by `article` and do search&replace `\paragraph` → `\subparagraph`, `\subsubsection` → `\paragraph`, `\subsection` → `\subsubsection`, `\section` → `\subsection`, `\chapter` → `\section`.

Comment: Thanks. The manuscript is long, and for such reasons not amenable to a straightforward  migration to scrbook. How may titlesec help?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Switching to `scrbook` is independent from the length of the manuscript. Same for switching to `article`. Currently I cannot see I reason, why you cannot do this. Maybe you should ask a question with minimal working example. And what do you mean with "How may titles help?". I've not written anything about "titles" in my answer. Do you mean `titlesec`? Have you read the `titlesec` manual and at least some of the questions I've linked?

Comment: Yes, I meant titlesec, and had already corrected the typograhical error caused by the auto correction. I was just reading the titlesec manual, and did not manage to find a solution.

Comment: Shifting to scrbook causes an unmanageable number of 210 red errors.

Comment: The number of errors is irrelevant, because a single problem can result in a very large number of follow-up errors. However, if you have a problem in using a suggested solution, you should as a follow-up question with minimal working example, because we can only help, if we can reproduce a problem. However, I've told two alternatives. Same for using `titlesec`: If you show us, what you've tried, I'm quite sure there will be someone who can help you.

Comment: Afte quite some work, for an hour, I succeeded with migrating to article. Your imput helped me find a quite satisfactory solution to my problems. :)

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Because this solution is also part of my answer, it would be fair to accept it.

Comment: @cabobah You are right.