# How to auto level-down section headings when \input-ing an document?

Tags: sectioning

I'm wondering if there's a way to tell (Xe)LaTeX to handle `\chapter` as `\section`, `\section` as `\subsection` and so on when inputting a document via `\input` into another document.

The setting is: I have a text with minimal LaTeX Markup. I need to use this text in two different environments / two different root files.

One produces my "standalone" Version of this text where I need big headings and the other one is a thesis referring to this text where I need to level-down the headings, because it's part of a `\chapter`.
Any ideas?

---

text file "text.tex"

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
Bla Bla
\section*{Point 1}
...
```

---

root file #1:

```
\begin{document}
\input{text}
\end{document}
```

---

root file #2:

```
\begin{document}
\chapter{First ideas to my text}
...
\chapter{My way to my text}
...
\chapter{The final text}
\input{text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This should be possible. Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26181/create-context-sensitive-headings

Comment: Thank you @egreg for pointing this out, i didn't find that.

Answer (score 2):

A quick trial, but I have to think about the numbering

```
\documentclass{book}



\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\latexchapter\chapter
\let\latexsection\section

\newcommand{\OneLevelDeeper}{%
  \let\chapter\section
  \let\section\subsection
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\OneLevelDeeper
\chapter{First Fake}
\section{Section Fake}
\subsection{Subsection Fake}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You might also want a `\OneLevelHigher` or, better still, to wrap this into an environment.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, but I saw, it's a duplicate ... I will come to it later on, perhaps showing another approach

Comment: @Andrew there is no need, just grouping does the job.

Comment: @touhami Of course, but environments are how one does grouping in latex.

Comment: Thanks for your very fast answer, @ChristianHupfer, I'll think it's the same approach as suggested in the dublicate thread under [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61803/76913) that I didn't find due to my small english vocabulary.

Comment: @JohannesHeck: No problem at all. I had no idea too about the already existing solution. I will come back from time to time to improve, I think