# Recursively import sub-document at arbitrary level

Tags: sectioning, import

**Note:** The ideas in this question and accepted answer have been composed into a [CTAN package called "modular"](https://ctan.org/pkg/modular?lang=en).

---

Consider the following `subimportlevel` macro:

**packages.tex**

```
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{coseoul}

\newcommand{\subimportlevel}[3]{
\setcounter{currentlevel}{#3}
\subimport*{#1}{#2}
\setcounter{currentlevel}{#3}
}
```

The purpose of the macro is to import a modular piece of a document while getting the section/subsection levels right, regardless of what imported the sub-document.
The problem with this macro is that the subimported file can change `currentlevel` so that the final `\setcounter{currentlevel}{#3}` doesn't do the right thing (it's supposed to reset `currentlevel` to whatever it was before the `\subimport`.

Here's an example usage illustrating the problem:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{packages.tex}

\author{Daniel Sank}
\title{Example}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\subimportlevel{./}{content}{5}
\end{document}
```

**content.tex**

```
\subimportlevel{./}{section1}{\value{currentlevel}}  % <-- can change currentlevel inside section1.tex
\subimportlevel{./}{section2}{\value{currentlevel}}
```

**section1.tex**

```
\levelstay{Section 1}
This is the first section

\leveldown{A subsection}
This is a subsection

\levelstay{Another subsection}
This is another subsection of the first section.
```

**section2.tex**

```
\levelstay{Section 2}
This is the second section

\leveldown{Subsection}
This should be a subsection of the second section.

\levelstay{Another subsection}
This is supposed to be another subsection of the second section.
```

Building `main.tex` results in the following output

[image]

Note that the second section is numbered as a subsection.
How can I fix this?
Is there a way to expand the `\value{currentlevel}` before the importing happens?

Comment: `\levelstay` and `\leveldown`? Where are those macros defined?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer They're from [coseoul](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/coseoul). I'd be happy to achieve this without coseoul though.

Comment: Am probably completely misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve but you can use things like \let\subparagraph\paragraph
\let\paragraph\subsubsection
\let\subsubsection\subsection
\let\subsection\section
\let\section\chapter

Comment: Do you have cross references within or between your sub-documents?

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn Yes. In fact I have several question on this site about that. I intend to post my own answers to them once I figure out this present issue.

Comment: My inclination would be to avoid this approach altogether and use sed to pre-process the files you are importing.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn: That's too bad. This whole thing has made me understand that TeX is not well suited to actually programming anything. Global variables and fixed depth section markers like `\section` preclude rational programming.

Comment: Don't think that - but if you want to go this route (and I think it is interesting) I think you need to make this a whole lot simpler so that it can be debugged. You have nested subimportlevels for a start so my head is spinning. Does a simple \setcounter{currentlevel}{5} do as expected? Without looking at the packages involved I don't know whether the current level is actually even set before it is used in a header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

My first definition of `\subimportlevel` (see below) imports subfiles in a group to protect `\mycurrentlevel`. In this new solution, I use multiple macros (`\@currrentlevel0`, `\@currentlevel1`, ...) so no group is required.

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{currentimportdepth}
\setcounter{currentimportdepth}{0}
\newcommand{\subimportlevel}[2]{
  \expandafter\edef\csname @currentlevel\thecurrentimportdepth\endcsname{\thecurrentlevel}
  \addtocounter{currentimportdepth}{1}
  \addtocounter{curentlevel}{-1}
  \subimport*{#1}{#2}
  \addtocounter{currentimportdepth}{-1}
  \setcounter{currentlevel}{\csname  @currentlevel\thecurrentimportdepth\endcsname}
}
\makeatother
```

### First solution

I'm not sure I understand the question. The following solution could meet your need ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{coseoul}

\newcommand{\subimportlevel}[2]{
  \edef\mycurrentlevel{\thecurrentlevel}
  \bgroup
  \subimport*{#1}{#2}
  \egroup
  \setcounter{currentlevel}{\mycurrentlevel}
}

\begin{document}
\levelstay{A}
\subimportlevel{./}{content}
\levelstay{B}
\end{document}
```

**section1.tex**

```
\levelstay{Section 1}
This is the first section

\leveldown{A subsection}
This is a subsection

\levelstay{Another subsection}
This is another subsection of the first section.
```

**section2.tex**

```
\levelstay{Section 2}
This is the second section

\leveldown{Subsection}
This should be a subsection of the second section.

\levelstay{Another subsection}
This is supposed to be another subsection of the second section.
```

**content.tex**

```
\subimportlevel{./}{section1}
\levelstay{Test}
\subimportlevel{./}{section2}
\leveldown{Test}
\subimportlevel{./}{section2}
```

Comment: This looks like what I've been trying to do. Would you mind annotating the solutions a bit? For example, in the first solution, what is the purpose of the \bgroup and \egroup? Is that protecting mycurrentlevel from mutation inside nested invocations of subimportlevel?

Comment: @DanielSank Exactly:  a group (between `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, or between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, or between `{` and `}`)  confines most changes. It works in this particular MWE... But, I think that it is a bad general solution.

Comment: Very curious as to why you say this is a bad solution. It seems like you've just taught me how to get TeX to use rational scoping rules! This makes so many things easier.

Comment: @DanielSank LaTeX sectioning commands (or `\input`, or `\import`) are not environments (or groups). It is a design choice. Here, by introducing a group, we change this choice just to protect `\mycurrentlevel`...

Comment: I think I understand. Normally we would have to \subimportlevel all of the files in `content.tex` within a single macro in order to get proper control over currentlevel. Using the group makes it a little easier.

Comment: This doesn't actually do what we want. Section "A" and "Section 1" are at the same level, whereas we want Section 1 to be a level below A. Just using `\leveldown{Section 1}` wouldn't count because the whole point is to have **section1.tex** stand on its own, i.e. be able to use it as it's own complete document. I think this might be fixable with just some adjustments to the imports. Working on it.

Comment: Is there a way to (optionally) make `\thecurrentlevel` increment +1 within the stuff imported by `\subimportlevel`?

Comment: In other words, I think we need a `\subimportleveldown`.

Comment: @DanielSank With `coseoul` package, you can't down the current level without insert a title. So, your new `\subimportleveldown` macro should insert a new title before import a file.

Comment: Actually, I figured out exactly how to do what I want. We just need an `\addtocounter{currentlevel}{-1}` right before the `\subimport`. I've edited your answer to indicate this.