# Generic alternative to \section, \subsection, etc

Tags: sectioning, nesting, structure, organisation

I often find myself changing the structure of my document, and having to change all sections to subsections (or vice versa), etc.

Is there a way to use something like nested brackets or indentation instead (as in code), to avoid this? Or perhaps have each (sub)*section specify its parent? Maybe there is a package that offers an alternative to (sub)*sections?

What matters to me is the relative relation between a (sub)*section and its context. Similarly to how I don't need to worry about manually numbering sections, I don't want to have to worry about how many "sub" I need to get to the right nesting depth.

P.S.: Please don't downvote the question before giving me a chance to improve it, I'm sure it's not perfect, and am very willing to improve/fix it if told how to do so.

Comment: ps. there's less down votes here because... there's less traffic. Just make sure your question makes sense. Preferably give a MWE.

Comment: Actually... looking around there's [sectioning - Create context sensitive headings - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26181/create-context-sensitive-headings?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [sectioning - Demoting/Promoting sections, chapters, etc - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61766/demoting-promoting-sections-chapters-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well. More answer choices.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks! In the comments of the answer to the question from your second link, there is a link to a package (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/coseoul) that seems to answer my question. Feel free to add it as an answer. Otherwise, I can add it myself.

Comment: I was thinking nested level environments, but then you would simply be replacing \uplevel with \end{downlevel}.  At least it would do some context checking (`\@currenv`).