# Dynamic (sub)sections?

Tags: sectioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create context sensitive headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26181/create-context-sensitive-headings)

I am working on a rather large document, where the final structure is not quite clear. As another dozen people are working on it, we decided to make heavy use of `\input` and put everything that is a self-contained topic in its own file.

However, assuming we move one topic to another part of the document, it may be necessary to adjust the `\section` and `\subsection` etc for this part, potentially crossing multiple files.

Is there a way to "know" the current level of section, and just increase it in some generic fashion?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This looks related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26181/create-context-sensitive-headings and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9024, perhaps those questions could be of help.